# Loop Analysis (find Vo in the circuit)

Tags: circuit-analysis

My working:
I1 = 2mA,
I2 = 4mA,
I3 = 4mA

Loop for I4,
2k(I4 - I3) + 1k(I1 + I4 - I3) + 1k(I2 + I4) = 0

2k(I4 - 4m) + 1k(2m + I4 - 4m) + 1k(4m + I4) = 0

2k(I4) + 1k(I4) + 1k(I4) - 8 - 2 + 4 = 0

4k(I4) - 6 = 0

I4 = 6/4k = 1.5m

Vo = 1k (I1 + I4 - I3)

Vo = 1k (2m + 1.5m - 4m)
     = -0.50V

May I know where did I do wrong?[image]

Comment: Have you tried simulating your circuit in a Spice simulator? Two birds one stone. =-D

Comment: You forgot about the voltage source. Also for loop 4 "I4" should always be first to reduce the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct loop 4 equation looks like this :

$$ (I_4 - I_3)2\textrm{k}\Omega + (I_4 + I_1 -I_3)1\textrm{k}\Omega +(I_4+I_2)1\textrm{k}\Omega - 12V = 0  $$

And the solution is \$I_4 = 4.5\textrm{mA}\$ and \$V_O = (4.5\textrm{mA} + 2\textrm{mA}- 4\textrm{mA})1\textrm{k}\Omega = 2.5V\$

Comment: May I know why is it necessary to put a ‘-‘ in front for the Vo equation?

Comment: I fix the error. Current enters "+" side of a 1k resistor so the voltage is also positive.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make I4 flow across two meshes; I4 should only flow around the lower right mesh. Your equation for the supermesh will include terms for I3 and I4, and you will get the final equation by inspection at the current source inside the supermesh.

Comment: No, in this case, one equation is enough

Comment: @G36 Which one, and why?

Comment: the one in his answer, why because i4 is shared by all subloops and superloops

Answer (score 0):

You went wrong when you said I3=4mA. That 4mA is shared between two loops. So, if I3=4mA there cannot be any current flowing in the other loop--which wouldn't make sense.

I think you realized this and tried to compensate by make I4 something other than the current in the 4th loop, but as you found, that still doesn't work out.